# Evaluating whether a function is outer or inner automorphism in $\mathrm{\mathbf{SL}}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

> For fixed $C \in \mathrm{\mathbf{GL}}_n(\mathbb{R})$, define $\varphi, \psi: \mathrm{\mathbf{SL}}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathrm{\mathbf{SL}}_n(\mathbb{R})$   as $$\varphi(A) = CAC^{-1}, \quad \psi(A) = (A^{\mathrm{\mathbf{t}}})^{-1}, \qquad 
>  (A\in \mathrm{\mathbf{SL}}_n(\mathbb{R}))$$

I've shown that both are automorphisms of ${\mathbf{SL}}_n(\mathbb{R})$, and I've shown that for C having positive determinant or n odd, $\varphi$ is an inner automorphism.

But I can't quite grasp for the case when $n$ would be even. Some reference I looked at stated it's not necessarily inner for $n$ even, but I'm looking for precisely when it is and when it is not.

Comment: Outer automorphism means the class of an automorphism modulo inner automorphisms, and hence is not the same as a non-inner automorphism. Write $\varphi_C$ for $\varphi$. Then $\varphi_C$ is non-inner iff ($n$ is even and $\det(C)<0$). Also $\psi$ is non-inner if and only if $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @YCor although the _outer autorphism group_ is a quotient of the automorphism group modulo inner automorphisms, non-inner automorphisms are commonly called outer automorphisms.

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos I'm aware of this confusing fact!